# How to drop offline datafile in oracle rac 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, offline, recover

I am trying to delete offline datafile which is totally empty. Database is in noarchivelog mode.
I am facing below error while recover and delete it:

> SQL> recover datafile '+DATA_DG/***/users_03.dbf';
>   ORA-00279: change 10988127 generated at 07/28/2015 19:02:34 needed for thread 1
>   ORA-00289: suggestion : +ARC_DG/***/1_52_879766576.dbf
>   ORA-00280: change 10988127 for thread 1 is in sequence #52
>
> Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
>   AUTO
>   ORA-00308: cannot open archived log '+ARC_DG/***/1_52_879766576.dbf'
>   ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +ARC_DG/***/1_52_879766576.dbf
>   ORA-15173: entry '1_52_879766576.dbf' does not exist in directory 'smp'
>
> ORA-00308: cannot open archived log '+ARC_DG/***/1_52_879766576.dbf'
>   ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +ARC_DG/***/1_52_879766576.dbf
>   ORA-15173: entry '1_52_879766576.dbf' does not exist in directory 'smp'.
>
> SQL> alter tablespace users drop datafile '+DATA_DG/***/users_03.dbf';
>   alter tablespace users drop datafile '+DATA_DG/***/users_03.dbf'
>   *
>   ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-03264: cannot drop offline datafile of locally managed tablespace

Can any please let me know how to delete?